# Variable becomes NaN outside for loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm curious how a variable can be an integer inside a `for` loop but become `NaN` immediately outside the loop.

```
var sumNum = 0;

for (var i = data.length - 1; i >=0; i--) {
    sumNum += data[i].stored_value;

    // check value inside loop
    console.log(sumNum);
}

// check value outside loop
console.log(sumNum);
```

Result:
The first `console.log(sumNum)` prints increasing integers as we iterate and add up `stored_value`'s in array. But the second `console.log(sumNum)` prints `NaN`.

I read a related thread ([Variable becomes Nan when i try to use it outside of the .each function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24879728/variable-becomes-nan-when-i-try-to-use-it-outside-of-the-each-function)) explaining how this could happen if variable is instantiated inside the loop, but in my case the variable is created globally first.

Could anyone share some insight on how this can happen?

Comment: what is the length of `data`?

Comment: please share what is inside data?

Comment: Less than 20 in above case.

Comment: Please provide the output of `console.log(data[0].stored_value)`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/suffpm5z/ fiddle does not show any problem.

Comment: It doesn't show any problem if tested with `data = [{stored_value:2},{stored_value:5}]`

Comment: chances of data[x].stored_value may contain some inappropriate value like Charcter/string which cannot be perform summation.

Comment: @Sagar R - `stored_value` in one of the objects was not a number... I think that caused the issue.

Comment: @pandaman : you can't perform summation in string (it must be some number).

Comment: @pandaman in that case the `console.log` inside too should have failed to show a sum? also if the value happened to be a string, `string+num` becomes `string + num.toString() = string` `NaN` happens when `undefined` is added to a number.

Answer (score 0):

add a check of number in following code

```
if(isNaN(data[i].stored_value) == false) {
     sumNum += data[i].stored_value;
}
```

Because if you add a non numeric value (may be some blank value) in some variable it becomes NaN